# Im trying to use typeid() but i keep getting an error C3867

Tags: c++, downcast, typeid, typeinfo

I am trying to use typeid() but i keep getting an error im not sure why.

```
void RandomAttributes(Shape * S)
{

// pointer need for down casting
MyTriangle * triPtr;
MyRect * rectPtr;
MyCircle * circPtr;

//downcast base class pointer to derived class pointer
if (typeid(*S).name == "MyTriangle")
{
    triPtr = dynamic_cast<MyTriangle *>(S);

    // reset the rectangle object to some known, legal values
    triPtr->SetPosition(p);
    triPtr->SetLength(S->GetWindowHeight() / 10);

}
else if (typeid(S).name == "MyRect")
{
    rectPtr = dynamic_cast<MyRect *>(S);

    // reset the rectangle object to some known, legal values
    S->SetPosition(p);
    rectPtr->SetLength(S->GetWindowHeight() / 10);
    rectPtr->SetWidth(S->GetWindowWidth() / 10);
}
else
{
    circPtr = dynamic_cast<MyCircle *>(S);

    circPtr->SetPosition(p);
    circPtr->SetRadius(S->GetWindowHeight() / 10);
}
}
```

a shape (base class) pointer is being passed into this function which could be pointing to a Mytriangle, Mycircle, or MyRect Object. I believe dereferenceing the pointer should be working but I guess not.

ex.
 typeid(*S).name

I already tried S, *S, and &S. So whats left??

Comment: Don't compare `char*` strings with `==`, and don't use the implementation-defined `type_info::name` for anything important.

Comment: `if (typeid(*S) == typeid(MyTriangle))` is a far more reasonable test. ;)

Comment: Wow that worked thanks. so what did i do wrong @enhzflep

Comment: @enhzflep `name` returns a `char*`, i.e. a pointer representing a C-style null-terminated string.  You don't compare `char *` for equality to a string by using `==`.  That is the job of `strcmp` or similar function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Yes, that's correct. Why are you telling _me_ this?

Comment: @Alvaromon - See Paul's comment.

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry, had put the wrong response name in the comment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - no dramas. Thought that was likely to be the case, but certainty seemed cheap to obtain. :)

Comment: The results of `typeid` are implementation defined.  You can compare them, but not expect them to have specific values (or contain specific strings, like `"MyTriangle"`).  Also the name member is a `char *`, so should not be compared using `==`.    In any event, `dynamic_cast<MyRect *>(S)` will give a `NULL` pointer if `S` is not a pointer to `MyRect`.